# Server Side JSON Paging

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, paging

I have a large JSON file I need to send to the client. I would like to paginate it at the server end; by having the client send me the next page number; because when I send the entire file it slows down the client interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a minimum parse on your json array to be able to page the way you want.

Take a look at the google gson library:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

You could store in your server just an array of objects. Then, once you actually have a java array on the server side, you can return just the objects your client expects, in json format.